# Can't run flutter web project in Release or Profile (Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isAsync'))

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, web, flutter-web

Can't run flutter project in release or profile. In Debug it runs normally without any issue but in other cases I'm getting these error in Chrome:

```
zone.dart:1413 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isAsync')
        at _GetItImplementation.$get$1$3$instanceName$param1$param2 (:61215/main.dart.js:164051)
        at _GetItImplementation.call$1$0 (:61215/main.dart.js:164063)
        at _GetItImplementation.call$0 (:61215/main.dart.js:164066)
        at :61215/main.dart.js:45288
        at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (:61215/main.dart.js:27970)
        at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (:61215/main.dart.js:69886)
        at _awaitOnObject_closure.call$1 (:61215/main.dart.js:69874)
        at _RootZone.runUnary$2$2 (:61215/main.dart.js:72668)
        at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleValueCallback.call$0 (:61215/main.dart.js:70794)
        at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (:61215/main.dart.js:28268)
```

My thoughts are that it is related to **get_it** but can't find any related issues...

Maybe somebody faced those issues and has solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some reason in **release / profile web build** when using get_it + injectable + bloc (as singleton) and bloc declared as simple class in **GetIt** method **call** (code snippet below) **type T** comes as **Object**, not as **your expected type**. GetIt tried to find this Object type in scope of registered types and (How unexpectedly!) does not find it and returns null. Null doesn`t expected and causes an error.

The problem causes only with singleton / lazySingleton. With injectable all seems good.

```
@override
T call<T extends Object>({
  String? instanceName,
  dynamic param1,
  dynamic param2,
}) {
  return get<T>(instanceName: instanceName, param1: param1, param2: param2);
}
```

So for me, the solution was to change from:

```
@singleton
class ExampleCubit extends Cubit<ExampleState> {}
```

to:

```
abstract class ExampleCubit extends Cubit<ExampleState> {}

@Singleton(as: ExampleCubit)
class ExampleCubitImpl extends  ExampleCubit {}
```